# Route certain domains through cloudflare warp and all other traffic go through the default WAN interface

Tags: cloudflare, www

I'm new to this subject. I have a ubuntu installed vps and vnc server on it. I want to use cloudflare warp only for selected domains/subdomains and all other traffic go through the default WAN interface. Trying to unblock 2 websites with it's subdomains. I have already tried cloudflare warp. There's a option to exclude a domain. But it's not practical to exclude all other domains while selected domains go through warp.

Thank you.

Comment: Simply point the A-records for those domains at your IP+

Comment: I don't own any of these domains. I'm just a user who visit these sites using web browser. I just want to route through warp and change my ip for only for these domains. Every other traffic go through eth0.

Comment: Go ask on superuser.com then.